# How to do write onto this script validation for the end "if they want to exit this program"

Tags: python, validation

```
problem = False
while problem == False:
    foo = open("solutions.txt","r")
    print("What is wrong with your device?")
    issue=input()

    if (('wet' in issue) and ('water' in issue)):
        solutions = foo.readlines()
        print(solutions[0]+solutions[1])
        problem = True

       # (and so on).
```

Need it to say at the end, "would you like to exit" and have an option of yes or no then say are you sure after input and if anything other then yes or no to say invalid input and ask the question again.

Answer (score 0):

Write it more pythonic :

```
while True:
    with open("solutions.txt") as foo:
        issue = input("What is wrong with your device?")
        if 'wet' in issue and 'water' in issue:
            print(foo.readline() + foo.readline())
        question = input("Do you want to continue? (Y/N)")
        if question == 'N':
           break
```

First off, note that you can simply use a forever-while loop with True and break the loop whenever you want, or as a question and break the loop wehn the answer is NO. Secondly, for opening the file you better to use `with` statement that close the file at the end of the block automatically. And for reading the first 2 line if your file is huge you better to read the lines using `readline` method.

Answer (score 0):

The next lines WITHIN your loop would be:

```
 answer = raw_input("Would you like to exit?  Enter 'Yes' or 'No': ")
 while answer not in ["Yes","No"]:
     answer = raw_input("Would you like to exit?  Enter 'Yes' or 'No': ")
 if answer == "Yes"
     problem = True    # This will cause you to exit the loop
```